# How can I automatically restore my site from a backup using the command line for testing purposes?

Tags: 7, backups, testing

I am on Mac OS X using MAMP PRO as my local development environment.  I want to quickly reset my site to a known state in order to run some tests I have prepared in Selenium.

I have the Backup and Migrate module installed which makes it easy to restore from the command line via drush, but if I restore using Backup and Migrate it appears to only overwrite the existing data and leaves other data in place, which I don't want-- I want to erase all of this other data as well so that I can be sure that the database is in exactly the same state as the backup file.

Currently, I log in to PHPmyadmin, drop all of the tables in the database, and then re-import from the backup.  This seems somewhat inefficient to me; is there a way to automate this from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `/applications/mamp/library/bin/mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE >backup.sql` to back my database up and then `/applications/mamp/library/bin/mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE <backup.sql` to restore it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Demo](http://drupal.org/project/demo) module. It's not command line but through the Drupal admin UI. It lets you create 'snapshots' of your database and lets you reset your database to those snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to script this process, I would recommend using drush.

If space is a concern than pipe the results to gzip as well.
drush sql-dump | gzip > ../backup/FILENAME.sql.gz

Remember it's a good idea to clear out your database prior to running your restore.

drush sql-drop - This drops the tables on your existing database.
drush sqlc < path/to/FILENAME.sql - This imports the file into your database.

With a compressed backup:

gunzip < ../backup/FILENAME.sql.gz | drush sqlc